How to write a script or task to increment version number in package.json
Is there a way to create a task that will increment a version number in package.json?
In my project that has package.json with a version number in it.
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.2.34"
}

With this task or script I want to increment the version number and then save the file. It can be a script but I want to be able to call it from terminal or on save.
Before:
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.2.34"
}

After:
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.2.35"
}


you can install the Node tool vsce, the tool to publish VSC extensions, it has arguments to modify the version number in package.json

After writing your script you can check Changesets package out, built for that

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-version?

An answer can be found here: update package.json version automatically
